# Compressing bitmap twice results in a bigger file size than the first compression

Tags: java, android, performance

```
public static File createBitmapToFile(File file, Bitmap bmp, int quality) {
    try {
        OutputStream out = FileUtils.openOutputStream(file);

        // First compression
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, out);

        // Second compression
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, out);

        out.flush();
        out.close();

        return file;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I still don't know why the second compression results in a bigger file size. I use 70 as quality.

Am I doing something wrong thing here? Isn't it when you compress something and compress it again shouldn't it be smaller?

My goal is to not exceed 100k bytes so when I exceed it I need to lower the file size.

Comment: Files that are already compressed have little redundancy, so trying to compress them even more may even add 'compression metadata' without gain.

Comment: @M.leRutte my goal is to make sure that file size is not bigger than 100k bytes before sending it to server. So when it exceeds that I want to lower the file size again.

Comment: You write that bitmap twice in the same file. So the file is twice in size. Please give exact figures.

Comment: @greenapps first compression results in a Byte size: 17381 while second compression results in Byte size: 34744. Because there are instances where it exceeds 100k and so I tried to see if it will result in smaller size but it got bigger

Comment: So you wrote that bitmap twice in the same file.

Comment: @pskink second compression results in a bigger size how much if it's 22 times

Comment: 22 times as big. Then you would have 22 jpgs in one file.

Comment: @greenapps let me try it out

Answer (score 0):

You aren't 'compresssing a bitmap twice'. You are compressing it once, and writing that to a file, and compressing it, the original bitmap, again, and writing that to the file, again. The result will be twice as big as one individual compression. Solution: use one compression.

Why you expect two compressions to be smaller than one, even if done right, is another question, but it isn't what your code actually does.